# Java - the graphics is disappearing after moving a window or minimizing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, repaint

I am writing a program in which different elements are being drawn (like rectangles and ovals). After clicking a JButton something is supposed to be drawn on the screen. I wish it could stay on the screen, but every time I move the window or minimize it, each drawn object keeps disappering.

I searched for similar topics, but nothing helped me. There are two ways: The graphic objects (each one of them) are being drawn after compiling the java program and they stay till the end (after using repaint() method) - this is not desirable, or after applying paintComponent(Graphics) method the objects are being drawn as I want them to, but they disappear as I've already described it.

Would anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should post some code along with your question to illustrate what you have tried and where exactly you have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I am writing a program in which different elements are being drawn (like rectangles and ovals).

There are two common ways to do this:

1. Create a List of Objects to paint. Add the Objects to the List and then override the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel to paint all the Objects.
2. Create a BufferedImage and draw each Object directly to the BufferedImage. Then you can just paint the BufferedImage.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both of these approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will definitely try out this approach.